# Do we need to install os language pack to localize wpf application?

Tags: wpf, windows, localization

I have a WPF application implemented with Gloablization feature.It uses satellite assembly to get localized resources.

I changed the Region and Language settings.System.Threading.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is changed but CurrentUICulture is not set.

Do we have to install os language pack? Or Is there any other configuration settings?

Thanks

Comment: No you don't. But you can also set the `CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: Yeah i can set but i don't want to do that. If we change the Region and Language, implicitly thread's CurrentCulture is changed. Why it is not happening to CurrentUICulture.

Comment: Well I'm not sure, one reason might be, that the user wants to use the frontend in another culture, than his current region. Take me as example. I'm a German but I like to use my desktop and applications in English.

Comment: Ok Got it. Like region and language setting, is there any other OS configuration to change the UICulture too? UICulture should be set so that the wpf application would be able to get localized resource from satellite assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the only solution is to set the `Thread.Current.CurrentUICulture` according to `CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` in the e.g. `Application.OnStartUp` method. Pls have a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710127/get-operating-system-language-in-c-sharp) and this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.installeduiculture%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) doc.

I think the following should do the trick.

```
Thread.Current.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
```