# Get Windows languege from kernel32.dll

Tags: c#, parsing, kernel32

I am trying to get language from kernel32.dll with GetNativeSystemInfo function as:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref _SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);
```

This function returns me a Languege Id (in my case 1033). how can I parse it in order to get a string representation of that language code?

I've tried to follow those links, but I got lost:

**function doc**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318123(v=vs.85).aspx

**lang code doc**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373763(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710127/get-operating-system-language-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can use these :

```
int langId = 1033 ; 

Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(langId).Name); // en-US
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(langId).DisplayName); // English (United States)
```