# WPF: Accessing Windows 10 OS-level settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

In the title I refer to basic settings in the OS like the list of default applications. For example, that the language used in the OS *can* be accessed with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710127/get-operating-system-language-in-c-sharp).

My specific goal is to display some info about the default  `MediaPlayer` to the user. I don't need any implementation, it is more that enough, if someone would point me to a good article, or perhaps the `NamesSpace` I should use.

Comment: “My specific goal is to display some info about the default MediaPlayer to the user” which?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24974/4645236 might be helpful