# how to set startup wfp location according to windows display language c#

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, position, screen

i need to start my WPF form in the right bottom corner
and i succeeded doing this.

but if the windows in Hebrew then my WPF windows need to pop in the left-bottom.

i have tried  this so far:

```
var desktop = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
Left = desktop.Left - Width;
Top = desktop.Bottom - Height;
```

and i tried stuff like:
[detect os language from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479300/detect-os-language-from-c-sharp)

but with on success.

how can i detect in c# if the task-bar icons on the right or the left?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you went in right direction with [detect os language from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479300/detect-os-language-from-c-sharp)

It should be enough to check if

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft
```

is set to true.