# How to set and get browser language and regional setting in coded ui c# automation, while launching browser?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have project which has been deployed globally. SO in every country there is  different language.

I have requirement in our project to run automation in different browser language culture e.g germany,Uk,canada,US etcs.

I wanted to set browser related setting before launching application in automation.

How can I set it using c# code and how can i get all browser information?

Comment: Which browsers are being used? Which Operating Systems are being used?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Internet Explorer and Windows 7 or 8 the default language can be set through [command line](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc722068(v=ws.10).aspx) after applying one or more language packs to the Windows image. Running command line in C# was answered in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c).

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PathToEXE\intlcfg.exe –genlangini –dist:C:\windows_distribution -image:C:\wim_mount –defaultlang:en-US -f");
```

Comment: Yes i am using windows 7 and IE 11

Comment: Current browser language, culture, regional setting, date format,

Comment: Can we set any browser language using above code ...what you have given ---System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("PathToEXE\intlcfg.exe –genlangini –dist:C:\windows_distribution -image:C:\wim_mount –defaultlang:en-US -f")................................I did not get what does this code do with browser .... can you explain me ..please

Comment: The above code sets the default language. It is based on the assumption you've already added the language files. English US would probably be installed by default.

Comment: [Culture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479300/detect-os-language-from-c-sharp), [Region](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530350/changing-the-region-and-language-os-setting-programmatically), I don't know what you mean by date format. have you tried googling these as they appear to be answered on stakeoverflow already?

Comment: I have used below code to set browser language but did not working for me................. CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-ca");

            DateTimeFormatInfo dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();



            dateformat.FullDateTimePattern = "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt";// Date format of en-us



            ci.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;

            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder obj = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("fr-ca", CultureAndRegionModifiers.Replacement);


            obj.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);

            obj.Register();

Comment: What i want to achieve is ...i have to set different browser language using c# ..e.g. sometime ..english us, swedish, france like that ...will it possible using code ...

Comment: Assuming your OS has the language files installed, yes.

Comment: which language file ...frankly i dont know language file, i guess it is installed in OS  ....do we need to install it??....as i am using windows 7 ...and IE 11....i can set manually browser language and regional setting ...

Comment: I'm not sure where the language file is located. I think your questions regarding language files would be best answered in a new stackoverflow question. Have a look at the edits I did to this question including sample code.